# OpenVPN with Blue Iris

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I am trying to set up OpenVPN with Blue Iris. I have OpenVPN working and I can connect on my iPhone.

If I am on my home network, I can connect to Blue Iris.

If I disconnect and use LTE with VPN, it doesn't work.

My setup is a Server with both Blue Iris and OpenVPN Server on it, and my iPhone has the OpenVPN client.

My two questions are:

1. If Blue Iris is on the same Server as OpenVPN, will Blue Iris be available on the network by default? Do I have to also run the Client? Do I have to do something else?
2. If #1 isn't an issue, is there any IP address magic that happens that would make the Blue Iris server have a different IP when connected to through the VPN? Or that would be blocking traffic? I've verified my iPhone is connected to the VPN but haven't been able to verify it can access anything on the LAN with the same IP it would have if I was directly on WiFi.

Thanks for any help! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I did two things:

Add push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"

To server.conf.

Then I noticed the server said "Assigned IP 10.0.8.1" so I connected to 10.0.8.1:81 and it worked!